# how to compare and validate password and confirm_password in laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel-5

I have to add an employee in my page.Add employee page contains the fields employee name,password ,confirm password .I want to compare and validate the password and confirm password fields.And i have not write any code in controller.

//view

```
                        <div class="col-sm-12">

                        <div class="form-group">


                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" >Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6"> 

                        <input type="password" class="form-control"   placeholder="Enter Your Password"  name="password" id="password" data-parsley-trigger="change"  data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-minlength="6" 
                         data-parsley-equalto="#password"  data-parsley-maxlength="14" required> 


                        {!! $errors->first('password', '<label class="control-label" for="password">:message</label>')!!}

                          </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>

                      <div class="col-sm-12">

                      <div class="form-group">

                      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" >Confirm Password</label>

                      <div class="col-md-6"> 

                     <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Re-Enter The Password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation"  data-parsley-trigger="change"  data-parsley-required="true"  data-parsley-equalto="#password" data-parsley-minlength="6" data-parsley-maxlength="14" required>

                     {!! $errors->first('password_confirmation', '<label class="control-label" for="password_confirmation">:message</label>')!!}

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

//

Answer (score 2):

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-confirmed)

> **confirmed**
>
> The field under validation must have a matching field of `foo_confirmation`. For example, if the field under validation is `password`, a matching `password_confirmation` field must be present in the input.

An example

```
<form action="/" method="post">
      {{ csrf_field() }}

      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">

      <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control">
                
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
                   
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, [
        'password' => 'required|confirmed'
    ]);

   // process request
}
```